# Implementing the HHL algorithm with negative eigenvalues (Cirq)

Tags: programming, quantum-algorithms, cirq, hhl-algorithm

How do I implement the HHL with negative eigenvalues?

This paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.01486) says that:

> what if $\lambda<0$? This problem actually does not hard to solve, since we can choose $t$ small enough, such that $|\lambda t| < \pi$. So if $2 \pi y/N > \pi$, then we believe that $\lambda t = 2 \pi y/N − 2\pi=−2\pi (N−y)/N$.

However, doing so introduces a problem at $\lambda = 0$, where the solution diverges.

Note 1: In Cirq, the code only works where eigenvalues of the Hamiltonian is positive. How do I adjust this code so it also works with negative eigenvalues?
https://github.com/quantumlib/Cirq/blob/master/examples/hhl.py

Note 2: in Qiskit,the quantum phase estimation EigsQPE has an input `negative_evals`. It seems this adds one more ancilla qubit. What do that they do here?
https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.aqua.components.eigs.EigsQPE.html